How to reduce branches or branch penalty if the predicate is determined at start time?
Consider the following code. The bool predicate is either true or false depends on the user. So we can't tell which one is more likely.
if (predicate)
    logicA()
else
    logicB()

However, there is an advantage that, once predicate is set, it is guaranteed not to be modified any more.
My question is:

Will this case here actually introduce branch miss penalty? I have done some searching, and I understand the branch predictor in modern CPUs are quite smart. For example, they can dynamicly predict. So in my case, it could be that the predictor found the predicate is always true, so it will then switch to always predict logicA().
If the branch miss is not evictable, is there any way to optimize my problem? To my knowledge, Linux can rewrite its codes to switch from "debug" mode and "no-debug" mode. This strategy certainly won't apply to my case, because it is hard to define the "start time" itself. When should the compiler or CPU start to presume predicate is initialized and will not change anymore? I think it is a tough task for them. So I wonder if you could come up with some brilliant ideas?


It sounds like you're saying that predicate is only set once, and once set, is always either true or false subsequently. So why is your code testing against it repeatedly? Forgive me if this is a naive question.

If you want to bind once for all a runtime choice to a specific implementation, you might have the possibility to make this choice at a high level in your program (see here to get the idea). Then the test is done once and only once. Of course, it is not always possible to use such a scheme.

@Chris Because there are many places of codes that rely on this predicate.

"When should the compiler or CPU start to presume predicate is initialized and will not change anymore?" -- A variable is initialized when it comes into existence, so if you used the terminology correctly, a compiler can always assume that a variable has been initialized (or lacked initialization, as the case may be). As for not changing, maybe there is a language feature that conveys the fact that a variable has a constant value? Did you over-simplify your scenario?

Question is to abstract to be able to improve anything. To remove branches we need fully working code with explanation what it does, then we could recommend how to improve this code using different methods (like branchless programing - doing more faster).

@JaMiT I have quoted the start time here because it is not the real start time at which the problem starts to construct all global or const variables in different section. The quoted "start time" is the time at which the problem has loaded the config, or parsed the input argument, and begins to actually do something.

@MarekR However, firstly I do not know if there is a common sense that the modern CPU has been already able to do this. Just like the "dynamicly predict" I have mentioned in my question, I have read some blogs talking about this, but I do not know this very well. It seems that if the CPU could perform the dynamic prediction, then this is not an actual problem? However, If it is still considered as a problem, then comes my second question that what "hidden parameter" is responsible for the behaviour of CPU here?

@calvin "I have quoted the start time here because [...]" -- That's nice, but not relevant to my comment. I questioned your use of "initialized", not "start time" (in fact, "time" does not appear in my comment). And if you meant something other than "initialized" (like "calculated" or "read"), there is a question as to what your code should do if it is executed before predicate is configured. (Or perhaps the question should be: at what point do you presume predicate is set?)

Branch prediction depends on the cpu and brand. There's no generic answer and nobody is an expert on every architecture. If the value is not statically available, bets are off for compiler optimization too. You now need to consider your design. It could make sense to have a static variable to hold the value and try branchless tricks on the result. You can store a static function pointer for each decision point and somehow initalize them based on the initial perdicate result.

If you are worried about branch penalties on testing predicate multiple times, probably best to reorganise your code so it only tests predicate once.    And test on target architectures to determine if doing so has a worthwhile benefit.

@Red.Wave In the answer, there is a comment which says branch prediction is currently better than jump prediction.

@calvin that's a false assertion. Because function pointer initialization is supposed to happen once the perdicate is evaluted. Rest of code contains unconditional jumps. One could even conditionally load dlls and load a C++ interface from the dll, but that's too expensive.

@Red.Wave I think what you've said is very important. Could you also comment the answer below, since other readers may not go through the comments here when reading that answer.

If your predicate switches from a run a falses to a run of trues, then the branch predictor should have some misses the first handful of trues, then switch to an accurate prediction thereafter.
If this turns out to be too expensive, then you can use a function pointer as the thing you call, and reassign it once when the user does the thing. This might affect other optimizations though (such as inlining), so it's really anyone's guess.
I'd measure on target architectures.

Calling function pointers will still need to do branch prediction.

@interjay It will be an unconditional jump.

@JohnFilleau: not unconditional, as it rely on a variable, so jump prediction instead of branch prediction. And as I understand, branch prediction is currently better than jump prediction.

Well I learned something today!

@Jarod42 your comment doesn't make sence. Jump==branch in every HW context. Branch prediction alway refers to conditional branching, because otherwise, the pipeline scheduler reorders unconditional jumps to give them enough time to fetch and avoid pipeline bubbles. By separating condition from branch, the branch prediction essentially goes away. Using immutable function pointers doesn't trigger any prediction. One implementation is to conditionally load a dll with interface to required functions: Either "user.dll" or "admin.dll", depending on the predicate.

@Red.Wave: I'm not familiar with asm and HW, but there are conditional jumps (to fixed address) (branch prediction) and there are unconditional jump/call to location stored in memory (jump prediction). function pointer would go in second category. Unless I misunderstand things.

@Jarod42 you need basic studies on modern cpu architecture. Otherwise, it wouldn't be recommended to consider optimization issues. The pointer - you are worried about - is not a major issue, but a misspredicted branch is; because it wastes CPU resources on executing usless opcodes that need reverting. Branchless programming is a paradigm focused on speeding up via avoiding conditional branching. Locality of reference is usually not a serious concern for code segments; they can often be optimized with correct compile options; When that fails, function pointers are the focus of ad-hoc.

"The pointer - you are worried about - is not a major issue" I don't see how void (*f)() = foo_or_other_function_pointer(); f(); is not also problematic, if prediction says that f == &foo whereas it is would be actually bar, useless foo part would also need reverting.
